# Python Layer Not Found

Tags: python, layer, psd

I am getting an issue in my code that is trying to read a psd file without opening photoshop but psd_tools cannot find the layer I want and gives me an error. How can I fix it. (already checked if there is any layer name typos and capitals)

```
from psd_tools import PSDImage
import os


def change_text_content_and_save(psd_file_path, layer_name, new_text, output_directory):
    try:
        # Open the PSD file
        psd = PSDImage.open(psd_file_path)

        # Find the text layer by name
        text_layer = None
        for layer in psd:
            if layer.name == layer_name and hasattr(layer, 'text_data'):
                text_layer = layer
                break

        if text_layer:
            # Change the text content
            text_layer.text_data.text = new_text
            print(f"Changed text content of layer '{layer_name}' to: {new_text}")

            # Generate the output filename (PSD format)
            output_file_name = os.path.basename(psd_file_path)
            output_file_path = os.path.join(output_directory, output_file_name)

            # Save the modified PSD
            psd.save(output_file_path)
            print(f"Saved the modified PSD as: {new_text}")
        else:
            print(f"Text layer not found: {layer_name}")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    psd_file_path = "C:/Text_Files/dalle.psd"  # Replace with the path to your PSD file
    layer_name = "emo"  # Replace with the name of the text layer you want to change
    new_text = "Mehmet Ali"  # Replace with the new text content
    output_directory = "C:/Text_Files/output_projects"  # Replace with the desired output directory

    change_text_content_and_save(psd_file_path, layer_name, new_text, output_directory)
```

GOT A ERROR THAT TELLS LAYER NOT FOUND

Comment: post full error message

Comment: Try printing all `layer.name`, does the file really have any layer, and your required one in particular? Maybe you misspelled the layer name?